# Seeking postcode shapefiles & census data for Netherlands

Tags: data, census, postal-code, netherlands

I would like to do some GIS mapping of the Netherlands, but I am having trouble finding official data files for the following:

- Shapefiles for postcodes.
- Census (population) data for postcodes.
- And/or lookup files to relate postcodes to other Census small areas (if they exist)

Of course I'm hampered by not speaking Dutch.

Can anyone direct me to such data -preferably governmental data not commercial data?

Comment: A lot of data is available from [Statistics Netherlands](http://www.cbs.nl/en-GB/menu/home/default.htm?Languageswitch=on), their [database](http://statline.cbs.nl/Statweb/?LA=en) is freely accessible, but frankly, it is not exactly intuitive. Even if you speak Dutch :-)

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask nowadays is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things have changed since 2015 I guess, currently there are multiple free methods to obtain data and geometry of postal codes. It is unfortunately slightly harder to find when one cannot read Dutch.

I've summarized the different ways of obtaining postal code data of The Netherlands below, the methods may lead to the same data.

- On the page ["Kerncijfers per postcode"](https://www.cbs.nl/nl-nl/dossier/nederland-regionaal/geografische-data/gegevens-per-postcode) ("*Key postal code figures*") of the Central Bureau of Statistics ([CBS](https://www.cbs.nl/en-gb)) you can find recent (2018-2020) demographic data in a shapefile on a PC4 level<sup>1</sup>.
  The same page has older (2008-2017) data on a PC5 and PC6 level.
- [PDOK](https://www.pdok.nl/) provides geographic data in The Netherlands. Amongst other things they have a [WFS and WMS feed](https://www.pdok.nl/geo-services/-/article/cbs-postcode-statistieken#85853f21a34b329b691769e28cf08f9e) for the same CBS PC4 and PC6 data.

  - Note that the PDOK services are limited to 1000 records per call. If you want to retrieve all data, you need to use paging, by appending this parameter: `&startindex={starting at this 0-based index}`
  - PDOK has a [QGIS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pdokservicesplugin/) allowing you to easily add the postal code data in QGIS as a layer, without manually downloading the shapefile.
  - To retrieve the number of residents per PC4 zone in 2017 you could use the following URL parameters:

```
https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/cbspostcode4/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&typeName=postcode42017&propertyName=(postcode,aantal_inwoners)&outputFormat=json
```

- Esri Netherlands through their [ArcGIS Hub](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-hub/overview), offers shapefiles on a [PC2](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esrinl-content::postcodevlakken-pc-2/about) and [PC4](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esrinl-content::postcodevlakken-pc-4/about) level.

<sub>1. PC4 indicates that only the first four characters of the postal code are used as a key, e.g. if the full postal code is 1011AA, the data aggregates information for all postal codes starting with **1011**.

Similarly PC5 refers to the first 5 characters (e.g. all postal codes starting with **1011A**). PC6 is equal to the full postal code.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Note:

> PostNL has been assigned by the Dutch government to carry out the UPD
>   (Universele Postdienst, Dutch for Universal Postal Service). This
>   means that PostNL has to deliver mail throughout the Netherlands, five
>   days a week (Tuesday through Saturday), and have enough mailboxes and
>   post offices available for posting mail. ACM is charged with
>   monitoring and enforcing the execution by PostNL

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostNL

**The Basic version** is a merged database containing the postal code ranges
€ 609.00 ex VAT (ex Taxes) (in euros)

**The professional version** is available as merged or normalized database, which covers the zip code ranges building numbers. The house numbers are also complemented by a number of characteristics such as coordinates
€ 999.00 ex VAT (ex Taxes) (in euros)

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=nl&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.postcode.nl%2F

Demo Data
https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=nl&tl=en&u=https://www.postcode.nl/producten/nationale-postcodedatabase-demobestanden&usg=ALkJrhicC_c0mgJD4H4Uf_ys4rUxusUIxw

Official Site is
https://www.postcode.nl/

Comment: Thank you Mapperz but those files don't seem to include shapefiles which is what I need (unless I'm missing something). I also need to be able to relate postcodes to population data. This seems much harder in Holland than for example the UK

Comment: you have to use a GIS to make them QGIS will do it easily. There is NO official shapefiles for dutch postcodes without coming from a commercial business

Comment: or pay a commercial company http://www.gfk-geomarketing.com/en/digital_maps/netherlands.html to get shapefiles directly

Answer (score 0):

Think, [this](https://data.overheid.nl/data/dataset/wijk-en-buurtkaart-2014-versie-1) is the best, you can find. It is in Dutch, so you need to keep google translator tab opened, but it has a lot of valuable census data for 3 agregation levels like regions, disticts, neighborhoods (buurt). For each neighborhood, if I'm not mistaken, there is a most common postal code. Hope it'll help, what kind of research are you doing btw?